# Long boot time - is it safe to remove any of these services?

Tags: boot, systemd, services

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (with a custom Plymouth theme), and it takes close to 40 seconds to boot.

The output for `systemd-analyze critical-chain graphical.target` is

```bsh
graphical.target @30.167s
└─udisks2.service @25.905s +4.261s
  └─basic.target @25.900s
    └─sockets.target @25.900s
      └─acpid.socket @25.900s
        └─sysinit.target @25.862s
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @25.697s +164ms
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @25.441s +239ms
              └─systemd-journal-flush.service @3.962s +21.478s
                └─systemd-journald.service @3.544s +417ms
                  └─syslog.socket @3.541s
                    └─system.slice @3.465s
                      └─-.slice @3.432s
```

Is it safe to disable the services like `udisks2.service` or `systemd-journal-flush.service` which take quite long time?

If not, is it possible to reduce there loading time?

I have a PC with an HDD, 4gb ram and quad core Intel i3 processor.

Comment: 40 sec boot time with HDD is about as good as it gets. You can disable `udisks2.service`, but it won't make much difference. I order to get faster boot times, you have to get an SSD.

Comment: systemd-journal-flush.service should not be disabled, right?